# How to execute delete and update operations in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

Just a simple, question reading through the official RavenDB [documentation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/csharp/indexes/querying/what-is-rql) , I understand you are able to execute these operations with the client API functions but you can't with RQL , or is anyway to do it with RQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is '**Patching**'
Use RQL with the [update](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/csharp/indexes/querying/what-is-rql#update) command
Inside the `update` you can delete (use `del`) or modify 
See these [examples](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/csharp/client-api/operations/patching/set-based#examples).